# Android without wallpaper - is it possible?

Tags: wallpaper

I've just got new S22 phone and wanted to customize it. I wanted to have just a black screen as background, but I could not find any way to do it. On s22 one needs to choose some wallpaper- there is no option None.
Then I checked my old phone and a new tablet - same there ...
Then I checked all the questions here filtered by "android wallpaper" - and found nothing ...

this is crazy?!

Am I missing something or is it really not possible to have "wallpaper : None" on Android? (just simple black screen background.)

(I know I could use black colored image as wallpaper, but is it such a "hack" the only solution?)

Comment: For reference on my Pixel 2 Android 10, selecting home screen background/Wallpaper brings up a bunch of photo/image options along with 'Solid Color'. I have it set to Black.

Comment: Just like OS and built-in apps, predefined wallpapers are also one of the things that can be customized by the vendor, so it depends whether they provide a solid black image or not.